# when i press (*) how to get (.) in TextBox (in C# WinCE)

Tags: c#, windows-ce

when i press (*)  how to get (.) in TextBox (in C# WinCE)

i have TextBox and when i press the (*) letter i want to get the (.) letter

thank's in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the keypress and if the key is a '*' then replace it with '.'?

[see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Multiply) e.KeyCode = Keys.OemPeriod;
}
```

if you can't set the e.KeyCode then you can do:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Multiply) 
      {
        e.Handled = true;
        tb.Text += "."
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank's for the help !!, how to get to the end of the text string ?

Comment: what do you mean? Last character? tb.Text[tb.Text.Length-1]